# How to find eigenvalues and eigenvector in python without Numpy library?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

I am trying to find eigenvalues and eigenvector in python without Numpy but I don't know how to calculate det(A-lemda*I) for finding eigenvalue.

Comment: Without numpy and for matrices larger than size 2, you are looking for a lot of work. You could try [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html#eigenvalues-eigenvectors-and-diagonalization), but then there will happen even more magic behind the scene. Note that apart from the pure calculation, numeric stability is an important issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Harsh Patel. Are you trying to write a routine for general matrices A, or for a very particular one? I think you should be a bit more specific in what your goal is. Eigenvalues and eigenvectors can be found in a symbolic way, but also numerically using eigenvalue solver routines.

Comment: Yes I am trying to write for general matrix A not for any particular matrix but I want to write for 3*3 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid using numpy.linalg (why? This must be some sort of a learning problem, surely), you can e.g.  implement a variant of a qr algorithm: factorize A into the product of Q@R, multiply R@Q, repeat until convergence.

However, if it's indeed a learning exercise, your best bet is to pick a textbook on numerical linear algebra.
And if it is not, then keep in mind that you are *very* unlikely to outperform (in any definition of performance) the tried-and-tested lapack routines that numpy.linalg wraps.